# Calculate nextDueDate based on intervals using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, momentjs, jestjs

I need help writing a function that gets the `nextDueDate` based on an `initialDueDate` with different intervals (`quarterly`, `yearly` and `monthly`).

pseudo code for that method would look something like --

If `initialDueDate` is in the future, return `initialDueDate` 
otherwise, if interval is `quarterly`, keep adding 3 months to `initialDueDate` until you find a date that’s in the future.

It's this test I am trying to pass:

```
describe('time helper', () => {
  describe('when initialDueDate is in the future', () => {
    it('returns the initialDueDate when in the future', () => {

      const fakeNow = moment({ y: 2016, M: 0, d: 0 });
      Date.now = jest.fn(() => fakeNow.valueOf());

      const initialDueDate = moment({ y: 2016, M: 0, d: 14 });

      const value = time.calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate, 'quarterly');

      expect(value).toEqual(initialDueDate);

      });
  });

  describe('when initialDueDate is in the past', () => {
    it('returns the correct date when interval is quarterly');
    it('returns the correct date when interval is monthly');
    it('returns the correct date when interval is yearly');
    it('throws an error when initialDueDate parameter is invalid');
    it('throws an error when interval parameter is invalid');
});
```

Comment: Looks like you've started... what problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to add a few things to [Yohanes Gultom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862500/yohanes-gultom)' answer. Handling the future case and making the function recursive. Hope it helps.

```js
// test.js
const INTERVAL = {
  monthly: moment.duration(1, 'months'),
  quarterly: moment.duration(3, 'months'),
  yearly: moment.duration(1, 'years')
}

function calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate, intervalCode) {
  if(moment().diff(initialDueDate) < 0)
    return initialDueDate;
  else 
  return calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate.add(INTERVAL[intervalCode]), intervalCode);
}

// usage
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'monthly').format('YYYY-MM-DD') )
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'quarterly').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(moment('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'yearly').format('YYYY-MM-DD') )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: works perfect! How do I check for valid param for `initialDueDate` and `intervalCode`. Sorry I am a newbie and thanks for your patience!

Comment: Check moment's [isValid](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) function. You can check for intervalCode if it exists in an array of allowed values.

Comment: Isn't it happening now ?

Comment: Which test fails, what are the input, output and expected output ?

Comment: my apologies, it is working against `initialDueDates` in the past.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right past 1 month. For example, try the following code, which starts with Jan 31, adds a month, and then another, and ends up with March 28, when you probably want March 31: `moment.utc('2017-01-31 12:00:00').add(moment.duration(1, 'month')).add(moment.duration(1, 'month'))`

Comment: I added an entire answer because I had a mouthful to say :-)

Answer (score 0):

I like @anshulk's recursive algorithm but it doesn't take into account that months have different lengths in terms of days. From my comment:

> For example, try the following code, which starts with Jan 31, adds a month, and then another, and ends up with March 28, when you probably want March 31:

```
moment.utc('2017-01-31 12:00:00')
  .add(moment.duration(1, 'month'))
  .add(moment.duration(1, 'month'))
```

Basically the same algorithm should work with setting the month directly with `.month(X)`. What's interesting about momentjs' `month()` is that it can go over 11, so 12 represents January of next year (not the same thing as 12 months from now), 29 represents 2 calendar years ahead, month 5 (which is June in moment).

So this should work:

```
function calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate, momentMonth, intervalInMonths) {
  const modifiedDate = moment.utc(initialDueDate).month(momentMonth)
  if (moment.utc().diff(modifiedDate) < 0) {
    return modifiedDate
  }
  return calculateNextDueDate(initialDueDate, momentMonth + intervalInMonths, intervalInMonths)
}
```

Here's a test:

```
// Usage:
var startDate = moment.utc('2017-01-31')
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(startDate, startDate.months(), 1))
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(startDate, startDate.months(), 3))
console.log(calculateNextDueDate(startDate, startDate.months(), 12))
```

---

Be advised that [moment's objects are mutable](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/)! This algorithm doesn't mutate the original value passed in, which may or may not be important to you.

Also, I used `moment.utc()` everywhere.